# (<class 'Pyro4.errors.ProtocolError'>, ProtocolError('invalid data or unsupported protocol version'), <traceback object at 0x0000018FFEF86E08>)

Tags: python, pip, opc, pyro, opc-da

I am trying to connect to an OPC DA server, but I get the following error:

```
(<class 'Pyro4.errors.ProtocolError'>, ProtocolError ('invalid data or unsupported protocol version'), <traceback object at 0x0000018FFEF86E08>)
```

I am using python 3 and my code to connect it as follows:

```
opc = OpenOPC.open_client ('myPath', port)
input ('press enter to continue')
```

When starting the script, it directly throws me that error, the connection tries to do it, since if I put another port it tells me that that port does not connect, but I don't understand why it gets me this error, my dependencies are these

```
OpenOPC-Python3x          1.3.1
Pyro4                     4.80
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this error? Thanks a lot

Comment: Same issue here: https://github.com/ya-mouse/openopc/issues/9 seems to be an incompatibility issue with each other. Their only solution was to downgrade back to python 2.7 and an earlier version of the dependencies to work.

Comment: thanks, the problem is that with the connect() it works but if i put the route it does not work, but when i try to write() something, the app crash and i dont recive the error, this is for the version too? thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue was resolved when I manually downloaded, extracted and installed Pyro4.8 ...
I shifted to newly extracted Pyro folder and used 'python setup.py install' ...
instead of using 'pip install Pyro4'